# Drupal RPC Fault

Tags: apache-flex, drupal, service, rpc

Hopefully someone can help me with this problem.

I'm starting to work with Drupal Services & Adobe Flex.  I created a simple service and installed the AMFPHP module.  In Adobe Flex when running the application, I don't seem to have a problem...and everything runs fine showing the data

However, after uploading the .html and .swf files to my webserver and going to the site [http://www.bkardi.com/top25/Top25UI.html]  I get the following error

```
Authentication Error [RPC Fault faultString="Send failed" faultCode="Client.Error.MessageSend" faultDetail="Channel.Security.Error error Error #2048 url: 'http://firejaypa.com/services/amfphp'"]
```

What's the best course of action to resolve this

Comment: Apparently #2048 is a Security sandbox violation

Still not sure how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the crossdomain.xml file