# Flex AIR Application Connecting to RemoteObject Through Proxy

Tags: apache-flex, air

I am having some issues trying to make an AIR application connect to a RemoteObject when the application is run in a domain that has proxy servers for outbound connection.

The error provided is as below:

```
[RPC Fault faultString="Send failed" faultCode="Client.Error.MessageSend" faultDetail="Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed: url: 'http://myTestService.org:8080/default/message/amf'"]
```

Any ideas? I think the proxy server may be preventing the application from accessing the Remote Object. How do I work around this?

Thanks.

Edit:
I saw a quite similar post to this:
[Remoting with AIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403806/remoting-with-air)

And I did declared the endpoint and destination to my RemoteObject.

Comment: I Would think you work around it by modifying the proxy server to allow such calls through?  I suspect the proxy server should have some type of logs you can examine to see if the proxy server is actually causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In application/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml give only relative paths, do not use ip address and port number. You can look here for detail [moving to production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022155/moving-to-production-server/14373832#14373832)

And here [send failed error](http://blog.themidnightcoders.com/index.php/2011/07/26/flex-remoting-urls-and-understanding-the-send-failed-error/)

In your case channel url should be

```
"/default/message/amf"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Drupal RPC Fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183495/drupal-rpc-fault) looks to be some what same as your problem and has issues with crossdomain.xml

Do check it.