# moving to production server

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I have a flex 4.5 php app that runs perfectly on localhost. When I upload it to my remote host, I come across a strange problem when I try to access the production release:

```
1. If I am the computer running my localhost, then the production site works.

2. If I am on any other computer then the production site returns the error: "Send failed Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed: url: 'http://localhost/public/gateway.php'"
```

In sum, the release build is looking for files on my localhost machine. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: (If you're trying this example in Flash Builder 4 then it will work. The problem occurs only in Flash Builder 4.5 for PHP when you try to run the release build on a remote server (you also have to access the remote website with your localhost turned off, as the .swf grabs files from localhost)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           xmlns:testclass="services.testclass.*"
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function getService(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            label2.text='this function did NOT work';
            testFunctionResult.token = testClass.testFunction();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:CallResponder id="testFunctionResult"/>
    <testclass:TestClass id="testClass"
                         fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
                         showBusyCursor="true"/>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" x="75">
<s:Spacer height="25"/>
<s:Label fontSize="18" color="Black" text="did this work?"/>
<s:Label id="label2" color="Blue"
         creationComplete="getService(event)" text="{testFunctionResult.lastResult}"/>
</s:VGroup>

</s:Application>




<?php
class TestClass{
public function testFunction(){
    return "this function worked";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your production SWF has some remote call that is hard coded to a localhost URL. You'll have to find that and change it.

I'd look at all the RemoteObject, WebService, and HTTPService calls the app makes.  If you use a Services-config file compiled into your app; be sure to look in there too.

Comment: thx. This didn't happen to me in Flex 4, only when I upgraded to 4.5. I can't find anywhere where localhost is hardcoded.

Comment: Are you using AMF/RemoteObject?  Or HTTPService?  Or WebService?

Comment: When you say that you are using PHP w/ ZendFramework does that mean you are using RemoteObject and ZendAMF?  Posting your project can be helpful in many situations; but in this case you should add some code to your original question.

Comment: I am using Flash Builder 4.5 for PHP, which has a different structure than Flash Builder 4. I am using Zend in both cases. The project files I posted work fine in Flash Builder 4 but break in Flash Builder 4.5 for PHP because of the new way they've separated the php from the the mxml. I will post some more to my original question.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Different Structure" of Flash Builder for PHP.  Flash Builder for PHP is just a couple of Eclipse Plugins (Flash Builder and some PHP one) bundled together as far as I knew.  The question I'm asking has nothing to do with the IDE; you could be using Notepad and the command line compiler and it wouldn't change my question.  How are you calling remote services? What tag are you using? I honestly don't know how to more clearly phrase the question.

Comment: You'll have to show us the code behind your "testClass" class; as that is the one that apepars [based on the code you've provided thus far] that is calling the remote service.

Comment: That is the TestClass.php..The project simply needs to communicate w/ a php file.

Comment: I recently upgraded to FB 4.5 for PHP. The project worked great in FB 4. When I run a release build under FB 4.5, however, and upload it to my remote host I get an error that says it can't find the gateway.php file....instead of looking for the correct place of 'http://www.myremoteserver.com/public/gateway.php' it looks for 'http://localhost/public/gateway.php'....the remotehost app will run IF I have localhost running but as soon as I shut off localhost the remotehost app throws that error.

Comment: If you haven't used FB 4.5 yet the layout for an app w/ php is different than under FB 4. They separate the mxml part from the php project. (if you download the trial version of FB 4.5 for PHP you'll see what I mean)

Comment: You're MXML code references a class named TestClass in the namespace testClass.  If that refers to a PHP file; then that is your problem.  You cannot use PHP files as classes in a Flex app.  You keep saying the project structure has changed.  Changed from what?

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Gaga,
I had the same problem. Solution is setting relative path in application/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml. I found solution from this video http://blog.themidnightcoders.com/index.php/2011/07/26/flex-remoting-urls-and-understanding-the-send-failed-error/

"Compiler EMBEDS channels, endpoints and destinations into SWF" video tells.

Firstly my channel definition was like this:

```
      <channels>
          <channel-definition id="my-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
              <endpoint url="http://localhost:8080/applicationRoot/messagebroker/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
           </channel-definition>
      </channels>
```

Then I changed to this:

```
      <channels>
          <channel-definition id="my-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
              <endpoint url="/applicationRoot/messagebroker/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
           </channel-definition>
      </channels>
```

Now I can connect server from remote machines.