# Flex application not loading in VPN

Tags: apache-flex, loading, vpn

My Flex application is not loading in VPN Network.

```
Error message: Connection Problems: Channel.Connect.Failed   
    error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP:  
  Failed: url: ‘http://172.16.46.246/PASSUS/messagebroker/amf’   
    -[RPC Fault faultString=”Send failed” faultCode=”Client.Error.MessageSend”   
                faultDetail=”Channel.Connect.Failed   
  error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP:  
    Failed: url: http://XX.XX.XX.XX/PASSUS/messagebroker/amf’”]*
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more details; but I'm not even sure where to start asking.  It looks like you're providing a Flex error from a failed HTTP call; but if the Flex app was failing to load you'd never get far enough to receive an error.  Are you sure the VPN is an issue here?  Does your app work fine when not signed into a VPN?

Answer (score 0):

Change your channel url in services-config.xml:

```
"/PASSUS/messagebroker/amf"
```

Do not use ip address. You can look here for detail [moving to production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022155/moving-to-production-server/14373832#14373832)

And here [send failed error](http://blog.themidnightcoders.com/index.php/2011/07/26/flex-remoting-urls-and-understanding-the-send-failed-error/)